# Search condition for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Category has_many products.

In category_index I defined:
`indexes :title`
`has products(:id), :as => :product_ids`

In product_index I defined:
`indexes :title`

In searcher class:

```
product_ids = Product.search_for_ids('word', with: {user_id: 5})
categories = Category.search('word')
categories_where_products_match = Category.search(with: {product_ids: products_ids})
```

How can I merge `categories` and `categories_where_products_match` into one `ThinkingSphinx::Search` object?

Comment: do you get a hash back when you get your search?

Comment: I get `ThinkingSphinx::Search` as result of search method.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to do here, it's only going to work when searching on Product. Your Category index can have many product titles, and many product user ids, but there's no concept of hashes or dictionaries, so there's no way for Sphinx to link the two separate collections together.

An index like this should do the trick:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, with: :active_record do
  indexes title
  has user_id
end
```

And then searching:

```
Product.search 'word', with: {user_id: 5}
```

If you wanted to get the categories that match this, then I'd recommend adding the following attribute to your Category index definition:

```
has products.id, as: :product_ids
```

And then when searching:

```
product_ids = Product.search_for_ids 'word', with: {user_id: 5}
categories  = Category.search with: {product_ids: product_ids}
```

Comment: What can I do, if other categories's fields match search condition and I need them too? I don't want to filter results using "with".

Comment: I don't understand - did you want to only include results with products for a specific user?

Comment: I have edited the question. Simply said I want categories that match 'word' too, not only categories with products.